# how do I conditionally bind a key to do two different actions in vim?

Tags: vim

I'd like to bind `<C-n>` to do one of two things in Vim depending on the state of the editor. If I have tabs open I'd like it to switch to the next tab, otherwise I'd like it to open a new tab. I've looked at the help and come up with this, but it's not working, and I'm a viml noob.

```
function TabBind()
    if range(tabpagenr()) < 2
        nno <C-n> :tabnew
    else
        nno <C-n> :tabn
    endif
endfunction
```

Is this possible? and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that you map a function that decides what to do on the fly.

```
function TabBind()
    if tabpagenr('$') < 2
        tabnew
    else
        tabn
    endif
endfunction

nno <C-n> :call TabBind()<cr>
```

Comment: You don't need the `:` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define such simple thing as one-liners. For instance I have the following mapping to go to the next diff (in diff mode), or to the next error message otherwise.

```
nnoremap <expr> <silent> <F3>   (&diff ? "]c:call \<sid>NextDiff()\<cr>" : ":cn\<cr>")
```

In your case, your mapping will be:

```
nnoremap <expr> <silent> <c-n> (tabpagenr('$') < 2 ? ":tabnew\<cr>" : ":tabn\<cr>")
```

Comment: I appreciate code golf and would probably use this solution if I wasn't a vim script noob I'd probably use this, but since I'm a noob I'm going to go with @buff's answer because it helps me understand vim script better.

Comment: This is still vim scripting. vim scripting has many sides : the imperative use of VimL combined with Ex commands, motions and actions (that can be referenced through `:normal` and `:exe`), the mappings and such (and in this case `:h map-<expr>`), etc.


Anyway, there are many nice tips/articles on vim.wikia about vim scripting.